# how to swap texture color effectively?

Tags: ipad, opengl-es, textures

I have an ipad opengl-es 1.1 app of a car, and I'd like the user to be able to change the color.  The 3d mesh is uv textured and it starts out in a basic grey color (with with shadows and highlights baked in).  I want to present the user with a dozen or so swatches of color, to paint the car.  I'm just not sure at this point how I would effectively/efficiently swap the color.

What I mean is, the current texture is 1024 x 1024.  Do I include a 1024 x 1024 texture for each of the colors available in my app?  I was thinking there might be an easier way, possibly if I could define a small 20 x 20 pixel representation of each color on the original 1024 x 1024 texture. Then somehow when the user selected a color swatch I could go and grab the color and "apply" it to the car.  Does this make sense?

I have all of the mesh lighting/color baked into my textures, so the app itself does not use lighting, thus just trying to change the color has no effect on my texture.  If I do use lighting, I am able to blend the gray texture with material color changes, but I really don't like the looks of this solution.  I'm looking for a texture specific solution (I think)

Any ideas or suggestions would really be great.  Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you just call the glColor4f(color you want) before the object draw? Shouldn't that blend your texture with desired color?

Comment: @Valerie You say you have pre-baked the lighting into the texture - do you have separate textures for the diffuse and specular parts? If not, it would seem to be rather difficult to 'realistically' change the colour of the car if they are already combined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the car I actually needed to set shouldUseLighting = YES.  With this setting I'm able to use multi-texture blending along with a color picker popup to allow the user various color choices.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you will be able to do anything other than just making more textures in opengl 1.1. But I think that is going to be your best bet anyway. If you were to change to opengl 2.0 and use a shader to change the colour, i dont think the performance will be too great due to having to do a lot of checks to see what range the colour lies, and change it to the appropriate colour. this will land up not looking smooth anyway.

I would recommend the multiple texture route. Textures that size are only roughly 4mb anyway so the space tradeoff isnt bad.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

Offline:

1. Create both a black, and a white, version of your car texture
2. Subtract the black from the white to create a new 'delta' texture.

Runtime:

1. When the player selects a colour, create a new texture (in software) multiplying the delta texture by the colour, and adding to the black car texture.

You only need to generate that texture when the colour changes. It should be a pretty quick operation, and the storage costs are minimal (essentially, two textures in memory, one for GL), for any colour you want.